# ¿Cómo ordenar una columna por decimal en sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, sql-server-2008

Para realizar el ordenamiento de una columna en sql server por decimal realice lo siguiente:

```
select CAST(Valor as float) Valor 
from Prueba.dbo.Tbl_Prueba
order by Valor
```

Los resultados que obtuve fueron los siguientes:

1. 2.34
2. 5.89
3. 8.22

Y yo quiero ordenar por la decimal para que me genere el siguiente resultado:

1. 8.22
2. 2.34
3. 5.89

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar `ORDER BY Valor - CONVERT(INT,Valor)`:

```
SELECT CAST(Valor as float) Valor 
FROM dbo.tbl_Prueba
ORDER BY Valor - CONVERT(INT,Valor);
```

[**Acá hay un demo**](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=642a38a20c496271f0ec662372a35af0) de este código y los resultados son:

```
╔═══════╗
║ Valor ║
╠═══════╣
║  8.22 ║
║  2.34 ║
║  5.89 ║
╚═══════╝
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Lamak, es justo lo que buscaba. :D